# Font rendering different on chrome for PC and chrome for iOS

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome

Working on this page: https://solderless.github.io

The title looks like this on my phone (using chrome / ios 10):

[image]

And like this on my desktop:

[image]

As you can see, the iOS version seems stretched horizontally (the 2 bars that make the L do not have the same weight for instance)

This is using Google font for delivering the fonts and the CSS is fairly simple:

```
h1,h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Any idea what could make the difference disappear?

Comment: did u try em units ???

Comment: @andrewsaeed em units is not gone change anything in this case. You probably have a rule in mobile overriding the `font-size`.

Comment: please can u elaborate ???

Comment: @andrewsaeed, Surething. The em unit is gone have whatever value your parent/parents has set in font-size (which is not a good thing to use for `font-size` in general), if you are gone suggest something atleast say `rem` (which is in general better to use for font-size in general), even that is not gone change as the are the same for mobile/desktop, unless the body font-size is different for the two devices. Now with px he is being very specific that I want 40px. So please elaborate your theory of the difference it would make? https://jsfiddle.net/def86sLq/

Comment: What do you run, mac or pc?

Comment: @Dejan.S: my desktop is a PC

Comment: It's been a while that I did a remote on a PC, but if you search for remote debug chrome/safari on windows I'm sure you will find something that would help you. That is the IMO best way to debug things like this, you can see the computed values for elements, in this case the font-size.